# Time given us or time given to us

Tags: grammaticality, present-tense, passive-voice, indirect-objects

I read this quote online:

> "All we have to decide is what to do with the time that is given us" - *J. R. R. Tolkien*

Is it just a relaxation of pronunciation of "the time that *[god] has* given us" ? Why did he choose to write "given us" instead of "given to us" ?

edit:
Is this form archaic? Because, at least to my non-english ears, prepositional phrase "to us" sounds more natural in this context.

Comment: Tolkien was also a poet: it scans better without 'to', without changing any of the meaning.

Comment: Given it's Tolkien, I can't help but think he was going for an archaic feeling to his work. I could be wrong, but I think in Old English all you need is a "we" in dative case ("us"). "þū us frēodōm gief", i.e. "thou us freedom give".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s simply a standard indirect object.  If someone gives us time, then time is what’s been given us.

The use of indirect objects in English is not archaic. It is normal.

> He **gave me** lots of “special” presents.
>
> Oh really? Just what sort of presents did he **give you**?

You would not normally use a *to* in front of those indirect objects; it wouldn’t sound right.